# Table with hide - show button when result is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Table, the code is easy to understand. The user will be asked by the code to give 4 int variables about 2019 and 2018 income - expenses.

`var a = parseFloat(prompt("Give the 2019 Income","0"));
 var b = parseFloat(prompt("Give the 2018 Income","0"));
 var c = parseFloat(prompt("Give the Expenses of 2019","0"));
 var d = parseFloat(prompt("Give the Expenses of 2018","0"));`

What i want to do is: When the user has filled the 2018 and 2019 income and both are 0 
the button will hide the zeros and the `<th> <b><p >Income:</p></b> </th>`
The same thing i want to do with the Expenses.
But when you fill the fields with 0.. you press the button to hide them and nothing happens

```js
var a = parseFloat(prompt("Give the 2019 Income", "0"));
var b = parseFloat(prompt("Give the 2018 Income", "0"));

var c = parseFloat(prompt("Give the Expenses of 2019", "0"));
var d = parseFloat(prompt("Give the Expenses of 2018", "0"));

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("button").click(
      function() {

        if (a == 0 && b == 0)
          $("#h1").toggle();
        else(c == 0 && d == 0)
        $("#h2").toggle();

      });
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = b;

    document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = c;
    document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = d;
  });
```

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 250px;
  top: 60px;
}

th {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

td {
  font-size: smaller;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<button>Hide when results are 0</button>

<table id="foo">
  <tbody>

    <tr id="foo1">
      <td></td>
      <td> <b>2019</b> </td>
      <td> <b>2018</b> </td>
    </tr>

    <div id="h1">
      <tr id="foo2">
        <th> <b>
                          <p>Income:</p>
                        </b> </th>

        <td> <b>
                            <p id="p2"></p>
                        </b> </td>
        <td> <b>
                            <p id="p3"></p>
                        </b> </td>
      </tr>
    </div>

    <div id="h2">
      <tr id="foo3">
        <th> <b>
                            <p>Expenses:</p>
                        </b> </th>
        <td> <b>
                            <p id="p4"></p>
                        </b> </td>
        <td> <b>
                            <p id="p5"></p>
                        </b> </td>
      </tr>
    </div>

    <tr id="foo4">
      <th> Monthly expenses :</th>
      <td> <b>2.500</b> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So whats the error?

Comment: when you fill the fields with 0.. you press the button to hide them and nothing happens

Comment: I think `$("button")` returns an array of buttons and so can't assign the click event. Try to select it by id.

Comment: you mean like that ?   $("#button1") and the <button id="button1">

Comment: To me it feels that if statement fails. It do accsess button but nothing happens inside!

Comment: i thing that to .. but how can i do it without if else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use`$("#foo2").toggle();` and `$("#foo3").toggle();` instead of `$("#h1").toggle();` and `$("#h2").toggle();`

Answer (score 2):

Working perfectly,you just need to use tr id instead div id inside Html table. :)

```js
        var a = parseFloat(prompt("Give the 2019 Income", "0"));
   

        var b = parseFloat(prompt("Give the 2018 Income", "0"));

        var c = parseFloat(prompt("Give the Expenses of 2019", "0"));
        var d = parseFloat(prompt("Give the Expenses of 2018", "0"));

        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("button").click(
                    function () {

                        if (a == 0 && b == 0)
                        {
                        $("#foo2").hide();
                            
                            }
                        if(c == 0 && d == 0)
                        {
                        $("#foo3").hide();
                        }

                    });
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = a;
                document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = b;

                document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = c;
                document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = d;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #foo {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            left: 250px;
            top: 60px;
        }

        th {
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        tr {
            background: white;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;

        }

        td {
            font-size: smaller;
            padding: 15px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    
</head>

<body>

    <button>Hide when results are 0</button>

    <table id="foo">
        <tbody>

            <tr id="foo1">
                <td></td>
                <td> <b>2019</b> </td>
                <td> <b>2018</b> </td>
            </tr>

            <div id="jdhj1">
                <tr id="foo2">
                    <th> <b>
                          <p>Income:</p>
                        </b> </th>

                    <td> <b>
                            <p id="p2"></p>
                        </b> </td>
                    <td> <b>
                            <p id="p3"></p>
                        </b> </td>
                 </tr>
            </div>

            <div id="h2">
                <tr id="foo3">
                    <th> <b>
                            <p>Expenses:</p>
                        </b> </th>
                    <td> <b>
                            <p id="p4"></p>
                        </b> </td>
                    <td> <b>
                            <p id="p5"></p>
                        </b> </td>
                </tr>
            </div>

            <tr id="foo4">
                <th> Monthly expenses :</th>
                <td> <b>2.500</b> </td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using .hide() instead of .toggle()

Answer (score 0):

remove the (c == 0 && d == 0) from your code in else statement. We don't compare values in else statement. It should work now